# How can I adjust indentation of my c source code in the entire selected block all at once?

Tags: emacs, block, indentation

I'd like to adjust indentation of my source code correctly at a time after I select some block of it.
Is there any function or key with which I can do it including parenthesis?

Here is original selected block of sample code I'd like to adjust indentation.

```
while(1)
{
    func1();
    if( )
    {
        func2();
       } 
            }

if( x == 0 )
  {
      aa = 1;
  }
```

This would be the correctly indented code how I just want to adjust.

```
while(1)
{
    func1();
    if( )
    {
        func2();
    } 
}

if( x == 0 )
{
    aa = 1;
}
```

Comment: Try posting here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with posting here (StackOverflow). Either place is fine. Just don't post the same question in both places, please.

Answer (score 3):

Select your code and press `C-M-\`, which should be bound to [`indent-region`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html#Indentation-Commands):

> `C-M-\`
>
> Indent all the lines in the region, as though you had typed `TAB` at the beginning of each line (`indent-region`).
>
> If a numeric argument is supplied, indent every line in the region to that column number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using evil mode because I like vim editing keymap.
In my case, block auto indentation can be done by equal(=) key after selecting a code block.
It's very convenient to rearrange block of code in a c-default-style.

```
(1) install evil package
(2) Insert this code into you emacs init file.
; indentation style for c, c++, java
(setq c-default-style "linux"
      c-basic-offset 4)
(3) select block using v and direction key
(4) press '='
```

Comment: Although this answers the question correctly, I downvoted it because I think a recommendation to install and run `evil-mode` just to indent a paragraph goes way overboard.

Comment: @Thomas, this is the OP's own answer. While I agree in general with your comment it is likely that the OP already had `evil-mode` installed and simply neglected to mention this in the question. OP, please do mention `evil-mode` the next time you ask a question. As you have discovered, this can make a significant difference.

Comment: @Chris The fact that this is the OP's own answer is exactly why I added a comment clarifying my downvote. I'm afraid that this fact might implicitly give credit to what I find an inferior answer to yours. I do agree that if the part about `evil-mode` is moved as a prerequisite into the question, his/her answer would be much more useful.